# How can I fix fatal RevSlider error in dashboard after upgrading to PHP 7?

Tags: dashboard, fatal-error

I can access the public side of the site. But the dashboard comes up blank.

The log shows an error pointing to the RevSlider plugin:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php:141
```

Here's the full trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(1143): RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(145): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(87): RevSliderAdmin->init()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(327): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/var/www/html/w...')
#4 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(304): include_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#5 /var/www/html/wp-config.php(81): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#6 /var/www/html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#7 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(22): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php on line 141, referer: https://192.168.16.18/wp-admin/plugins.php
```

Comment: RevSlider, AFAICT, is a plugin specific to Wordpress. I did try https://revslider.stackexchange.com/, but it 404s for me.

Comment: This might not be appropriate here, but was most useful to me as this error made accessing the admin completely unreachable after a PHP upgrade, and fixing it was not a matter of debugging what happened but just applying the hotfix from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by hotfixing the RevSlider plugin on my server as [documented here](https://xtemos.com/forums/topic/revolution-slider-error-crashes-admin-cp/#post-5852).

In `revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php`, I changed the following line (l. 21 of my version) from:

```
private static $arrMetaBoxes = '';         //option boxes that will be added to post
```

to:

```
private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();    //option boxes that will be added to post
```

Comment: You can use `[]` instead of `array()`.

Comment: Worked for me in 2018!

Comment: Great job! Just upgraded to php 7.2 on my server and this came in handy!

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer! In my case, I was using the churchHope wordpress template, and was getting an error on /churchope/lib/revslider/inc_php/framework/base_admin.class.php:72  - fixed this by changing private static $arrMetaBoxes = ""; to private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();

Comment: I owe you a beer. +1 and for the explanation, in php7 you have tighter restrictions on types so an empty string cannot have something appended to it while treating it like an array. As @fuxia mentioned `[]` also works here well and is more Pythonish.

Comment: in my case revslider was under: my_url/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework

Comment: Nov 2019 it works!!!

Comment: We encountered this error today when migrating to PHP 7.3 and this hotfix worked perfectly. As @AlessandroMattiuzzi mentioned, the path appears to have changed in recent versions of the plugin.

Comment: 2021 on PHP 7.4 this patch still works! Thanks!