# Why does this show up when i try to log in

Tags: errors, fatal-error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php:71  
Stack trace: #0 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(552): RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL)  
\#1 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(73): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox()  
\#2 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(44): RevSliderAdmin->init()  
\#3 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(165): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/home/mckinst9/...')  
\#4 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-settings.php(342): include_once('/home/mckinst9/...')  
\#5 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/mckinst9/...')  
\#6 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/mckinst9/...')  
\#7 /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): re in /home/mckinst9/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php on line 71
```

Comment: Because your slider plugin is broken. If you rename the /wp-content/plugins/ folder via FTP you should be able to log in, then rename the folder back, and reactivate all your other plugins. You'll then want to update the slider plugin or download a fresh copy of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix fatal RevSlider error in dashboard after upgrading to PHP 7?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260187/how-can-i-fix-fatal-revslider-error-in-dashboard-after-upgrading-to-php-7)